# Moving a button randomly onClick() with ObjectAnimator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this code:

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator  animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button3, "X", 0f, 50f);
            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button3, "Y", 0f, 50f);

            AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animSet.playSequentially(animX, animY);
            animSet.setDuration(500);


            animSet.start();
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to move "button3" with ObjectAnimator randomly across the screen for a set amount of time, but I can't figure out how to multiply the X and Y values to make the button position random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. In my example, I showed that the button moves only inside its container(id=**parentView**) and does not go beyond it.  I limit the width and height, you can change the value you want(or **match_parent**)

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        FrameLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.parentView);

        Random random = new Random();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                float randomX = (float) (random.nextInt(parent.getWidth() - button.getWidth()));
                float randomY = (float) (random.nextInt(parent.getHeight() - button.getHeight()));

                button.animate().x(randomX).y(randomY).setDuration(500).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int rx = new Random().nextInt(50);
                int ry = new Random().nextInt(50);
                ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button3, View.X, new Random().nextBoolean() ? rx : rx * -1);
                ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button3, View.Y, new Random().nextBoolean() ? ry : ry * -1);

                AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
                animSet.playSequentially(animX, animY);
                animSet.setDuration(500);


                animSet.start();
            }
        });
```